# How to determine is a value falls within a list of ranges?

Tags: c#, numbers, integer

I have an input type that contains a list of Min & Max values. What I need to do is validate the list to ensure that there is no overlap between the min/max values. The DTO looks similar to this

```
public class FeeDTO
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the fees.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The fees.
    /// </value>
    public List<IndividualFee> Fees { get; set; }
}

public class IndividualFee
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the minimum value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The minimum value.
    /// </value>
    public Int32 MinValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the maximum value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The maximum value.
    /// </value>
    public Int32 MaxValue { get; set; }
}
```

So for example, this input would be fine as all ranges are exclusive:

- Range 1: Min = 0   Max = 100
- Range 2: Min = 101 Max = 200
- Range 3: Min = 201 Max = 300

However, in the following example range 3 min value falls within range 2

- Range 1: Min = 0   Max = 100
- Range 2: Min = 101 Max = 200
- Range 3: Min = 199 Max = 300

My question would be, what is the best method to use for detecting this overlap between values?

Comment: Not exactly efficient but first oder them: `fees.OrderBy(x => x.Max)` then for each one check if next `Min` is greater than this `Max`.

Comment: Did you even try anything? Why should we do what´s supposed to be your job: thinking and trying?

Comment: Define best, Easiest to write? Easiest to use? Fastest to run in the majority of cases?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most obvious way to tackle this problem would be to create a foreach that goes through every max value and compares them to every min value. We can make the code a bit more compact with some LINQ as well I'm sure there might be a more efficient algorithm but this is what I can think of:

```
foreach(IndividualFee fee in Fees){
    if(Fees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.MaxValue > fee.MinValue) != null){
        //Code for if the ranges are overlapping
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could for example create a custom collection type that validates the data according to your logic whenever a new item is added, e.g.:

```
public class FeeList : ICollection<IndividualFee>
{
    private readonly List<IndividualFee> _list = new List<IndividualFee>();

    public int Count => _list.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public void Add(IndividualFee item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(item));
        if (item.MaxValue < item.MinValue)
            throw new ArgumentException("Overlaps", nameof(item));
        if (_list.Count > 0 && item.MinValue < _list[_list.Count - 1].MaxValue)
            throw new ArgumentException("Overlaps", nameof(item));
    }

    public void Clear() => _list.Clear();

    public bool Contains(IndividualFee item) => _list.Contains(item);

    public void CopyTo(IndividualFee[] array, int arrayIndex) => _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);

    public IEnumerator<IndividualFee> GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();

    public bool Remove(IndividualFee item) => _list.Remove(item);

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => _list.GetEnumerator();
}
```

You then use this custom type in your DTO class instead of using a `List<T>`:

```
public class FeeDTO
{
    public FeeList Fees { get; set; }
}
```

This should make sure that you can't add any invalid data to a `FeeDTO` object without an exception being thrown.

If you don't want to throw exceptions when the validation fails, you could just add an `IsValid` property to the `FeeList` and set this one as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, [Fiddle with tests here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Ks7Bs).

```
public static bool IsOverlap(IEnumerable<IndividualFee> fees)
{
    var limit = int.MinValue;
    foreach (var fee in fees.OrderBy(f => f.MinValue))
    {
        if (fee.MinValue <= limit)
        {
            return true;
        }

        limit = fee.MinValue;

        if (fee.MaxValue <= limit)
        {
            return true;
        }

        limit = fee.MaxValue;

    }

    return false;
}
```